# Wrong SHA-256 hash of a string in MessageDigest

Tags: java, groovy, sha256, message-digest

in some tests i using MessageDigest library in Groovy and sometimes this function returns incorrect value. Here is my code below:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
String.metaClass.toSHA256 = {
    def messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
    messageDigest.update(delegate.getBytes("UTF-8"))
    new BigInteger(1, messageDigest.digest()).toString(16).padLeft(40, '0')
}
```

for example - i tryed to encode to SHA-256 this string:

```
582015-04-23 20:47:112015-04-23 23:59:000020502015-04-23 20:47:11tests-from-api["afoot"]33facafaece3afd353bcbe88637d11b7
```

My method return
`cb2814380117cd5621064c1d7512b32e3cb8c8cb2b1f20016f6da763598d738`

But online generators, returns `0cb2814380117cd5621064c1d7512b32e3cb8c8cb2b1f20016f6da763598d738`

it calculates wrong like 2 times in 40 tries
Could you help me how to fix it?

Comment: You're using `padLeft(40, '0')` when a SHA-256 hash is 64 characters...

Comment: Isn't it just the same, with an extra 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a '0' at the start, because you're padding left to *40* characters (presumably having copied that code from something where the hash is expected to be 40 characters) instead of the 64 characters that actually makes up a SHA-256 hash (in hex).

So you *could* just fix the `padLeft` code - but personally I would just avoid using `BigInteger` for hex conversions. That's not what it's designed for - it's designed for maths operations on large integers.

Instead, use one of the *many* hex converters in common utility libraries - which are designed precisely to convert byte arrays to hex, with nothing about integers at all. If you don't want to use a library, there's plenty of code on Stack Overflow to convert a `byte[]` to hex.